# Primitive variable does not live long enough

Tags: rust, iterator, closures

There is an error in this piece of code:

```
let a: Vec<_> = (1..10).flat_map(|x| (1..x).map(|_| x)).collect();
```

The error message:

```
error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:2:57
  |
2 |     let a: Vec<_> = (1..10).flat_map(|x| (1..x).map(|_| x)).collect();
  |                                                     --- ^-          - borrowed value needs to live until here
  |                                                     |   ||
  |                                                     |   |borrowed value only lives until here
  |                                                     |   borrowed value does not live long enough
  |                                                     capture occurs here
```

But why?

Is is a primitive type, i.e. it should be cloned anyway.

What do I understand wrong?

Comment: I don't know if this is ur real usecase, but `1..10` is already an iterator. You can write: `let a: Vec<_> = (1..10).flat_map(|x| 1..x).collect()`.

Comment: @Boiethios Sure, I know it, but in this case it is just an example

Comment: Anyway, I didn't understand your code at first :P

Comment: @Boiethios Originally I generated tuples `|y| (x,y)`

Comment: Oh, then you can use [Itertools::tuple_combinations](https://docs.rs/itertools/*/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_combinations).

Comment: @Boiethios Yes, but in my case it should (at the end of the day): `1..x, x..y, y..z`; sure we can drop the rest with filter, but it would be wrong, I think

Comment: @Boiethios: But what I still do not understand, how can I clone the value? (`move` works perfectly though). The question is: why should I either borrow or move a primitive value, and why it is not just being copied? And how could I force it?

Comment: Move will copy the integer because it is `Copy`able. A move and a copy are the same thing for those types. You can [move it multiple times](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=24e1a8a7c61f58d9c3b701e8c1c4bc87) and the compiler will not complain. If you want an explicit copy, you can call the `clone()` method.

Comment: @Boiethios: I tried to do it with clone first (before posting the question on Stackoverflow), but it did not help. Where exactly should I add `.clone()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182818/discussion-between-boiethios-and-igor-chubin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not work because you capture `x` by reference when you do `map(|_| x)`. `x` is not a variable local to the closure, so it is borrowed. To not borrow `x`, you must use the `move` keyword:

```
let a: Vec<_> = (1..10).flat_map(|x| (1..x).map(move |_| x)).collect();
```

But this is more idiomatic to write (for the same output):

```
use std::iter::repeat;
let b: Vec<_> = (2..10).flat_map(|x| repeat(x).take(x - 1)).collect();
```

---

Concerning the "why" question: some people could want to borrow a copyable data, so the capturing rules are the same:

- Default: by reference,
- With the `move` keyword: take the ownership.

Comment: @IgorChubin Can't quite follow - what are you commenting on? Have you seen the previous edits of the answer? I guess I should clean up outdated comments.