# Accessing variable from parent iter().map from within a child iter().map is throwing 'error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough' on compile'

Tags: rust

I have come a bit unstuck on the third exercise mentioned in the [summary of chapter 8](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch08-03-hash-maps.html#summary) of *The Rust Programming Language*.

I am trying to return a list of all employees and the department they belong to:

```
let mut company: HashMap<&str, Vec<&str>> = HashMap::new();
company.insert("Dept1", vec!["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5"]);
company.insert("Dept2", vec!["user6", "user7", "user8"]);
company.insert("Dept3", vec!["user9", "user10"]);

let user_dept: Vec<(&&str, &&str)> = company
    .iter()
    .map(|x| x.1.iter().map(|z| (z, x.0)))
    .flatten()
    .collect();

println!("user_dept: {:?}", user_dept);
```

When I try to compile the above, it fails with the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:11:41
   |
11 |         .map(|x| x.1.iter().map(|z| (z, x.0)))
   |                                 ---     ^   -- borrowed value needs to live until here
   |                                 |       |   |
   |                                 |       |   borrowed value only lives until here
   |                                 |       borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                                 capture occurs here
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought `x` would still have been available to allow me to do this.

As an example, I know it is not the same language, but running the following in Scala does allow me to achieve the result I am after, and I thought it maybe a bit clearer to read than my above code (sorry about that!):

```scala
val company = Map (
  "Dept1" -> List("user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5"),
  "Dept2" -> List("user6", "user7", "user8"),
  "Dept3" -> List("user9", "user10"),
)

val d: Iterable[(String, String)] = company.map(a =>
  a._2.map(b => (b, a._1))
).flatten
println(s"user_dept: ${d}")
```

Is there something I've missed in the Rust version?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Primitive variable does not live long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53064925/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Also, `flatten o map = flat_map` (in any language, Rust or Scala), so maybe you should try `let user_dept:Vec<(&&str, &&str)> = company
      .iter()
      .flat_map(|x| { x.1.iter().map(move |z| (z, x.0))})
      .collect();`. And by the way: the Scala snippet could be written shorter as `for ((d, us) <- company.toList; u <- us) yield (u, d)`.

Comment: Thanks for that @andrey-tyukin, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would solve this problem:

```
let mut company: HashMap<&str, Vec<&str>> = HashMap::new();
company.insert("Dept1", vec!["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5"]);
company.insert("Dept2", vec!["user6", "user7", "user8"]);
company.insert("Dept3", vec!["user9", "user10"]);

let user_dept: Vec<_> = company
    .iter()
    .flat_map(|(&dept, users)| users.iter().zip(repeat(dept)))
    .collect();

println!("user_dept: {:?}", user_dept);
```

What you can see is that I used `flat_map()` instead of `map().flatten()` as this one can be more performant, and for sure is more idiomatic. Other change is that I have used `zip()` and `repeat()` instead of `map()`. Thanks to that compiler is able to understand that `dept` and `users` values will live equally long.

Comment: *should be more performant* — citation required. I expect them to compile to the exact same code.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin [fusion is all but guaranteed because iterators are lazily-evaluated](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=0f8ac17dffea84e145a9c537270c9f8a). Also, there's no closure passed to `flatten` ;-)

Comment: Performance aside, I do agree that `flat_map` is more *idiomatic* in this case.

Comment: Thanks for that @Hauleth really appreciate it!  I can now stop tearing my hair out :-)